# Is it possible to use one sequence of moves to solve the Rubik's cube from any position?

Tags: strategy, rubiks-cube, mechanical-puzzles, solvability, twisty-puzzles

Is there a sequence of moves that can be repeated over and over again which can solve any legal position the Rubik's Cube? If so what is it, and if there's more than one, what's the shortest? If not, prove that it's impossible.

*The sequence can be of any length but cannot be broken up into multiple pieces to be executed depending on Rubik's cube patterns; it must, when repeated from start to finish, end in a perfectly solved Rubik's cube.*

Comment: Can you just do all possible (`<20 move sequence>` followed by `<undoing previous sequence>`) as a possible solution? (might not be shortest but it'll show one exists) You'll solve the cube at some point.

Comment: @Sp3000 That's pretty long, the question asks for the shortest if one exists so.

Comment: Mew, was that edit some kind of joke -_-

Comment: @warspyking, indeed I hope you liked it :)

Comment: Lol, I have to admit, I got on the site and saw "Rubik's Cube Solve All Sequence? [Part 2!]" and I was like "What immature little jokster made a new question after I specifically said not to?" Then I saw it was my question, then I noticed you edited it. Lol I was so confused when it was mine.

Comment: The question might be better phrased as "what is the shortest move sequence which, if repeated enough times, would cause the cube to *pass through* every valid state".  Additionally, you may also wish to qualify whether rotating the *entire* cube by 90 degrees or 180 degrees about an axis perpendicular to a face, or rotating it 120 degrees about a long diagonal access, would count as a "move", since it's possible that including such a move at the end of a sequence might make it behave as a sequence which is 3-4 times as long.

Comment: Another potentially interesting question, if anyone cared to solve it, would be the shortest primitive-recursive way of writing such a sequence, if one could define sub-sequences and then unconditionally invoke each sub-sequence in its entirety simply by including its name, so [spaces added for clarity] "1 tr 2 f 1b1 3 22r12" would define "1" as "tr", "2" as "f tr b tr", and "3" as "ftrbtr ftrbtr r tr ftrbtr".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only way you can have a solve-all sequence is if you have a sequence of moves that goes through all 43 quintillion configurations of the Rubik's Cube. In order to do this, you need to draw a transition graph between all the states of the Rubik's Cube and find a Hamiltonian cycle through them.

This sequence of moves doesn't necessarily have to be 43 quintillion moves long - a simple sequence of 4 moves can produce a cycle of 1,260 configurations as seen in mdc32's answer, and in general a sequence of symbols in the group will produce a cycle of configurations much longer than the cycle itself. However, the sequence will still be very long, simply because 43 quintillion moves is still a lot.

Micah provided [a link](http://bruce.cubing.net/ham333/rubikhamiltonexplanation.html) to a page that did construct such a Hamiltonian cycle in a comment. I haven't been able to make head or tail of its notation (or to figure out how to count the number of moves from the descriptions of the cosets), but it looks like the sequence of moves that is required is billions of moves long, which is still definitely outside of the realm of plausibility for memorization.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily have to be 43 quintillion moves. Mine is only a four move sequence, technically, yet it cycles through 1260 states as you pointed out.

Comment: Really? That's really the ONLY way to do this? Wow... Are you sure there isn't like a 4 move sequence that can loop through them all or something? Even if it repeats a position but on a separate move?

Comment: @mdc32 You're right. For example, in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, the sequence $(1, 0), (0, 1)$ does result in the whole group being traversed, so the length of the solve-all cycle doesn't necessarily _have_ to be equal to the order of the group. And, as you pointed out, a sequence of 4 moves can generate a 1,260-state cycle. But I don't see there being a solution that's shorter than 10,000 or maybe 10,000,000 moves long.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Either way, the shortest solution is entirely impractical. That would be entertaining, though, just solving a Rubik's cube with one move over and over and over and over and over and over....

Comment: [It exists.](http://bruce.cubing.net/ham333/rubikhamiltonexplanation.html)

Comment: @Joe Precisely why I haven't accepted this answer, there's no mathematical proof this is the shortest solution.

Comment: A mathematical proof would be a research-level question.

Comment: @Joe Z. ? What?

Comment: A research-level question, i.e. a question that has no known answer and that only a professional mathematician could answer. Looking for a provably shortest sequence of solve-all moves is something that could probably even go on MathOverflow.

Comment: To work for any of the 43 quintillion cube positions, the sequence has to include all those 43 quintillion states.  The accomplishment of Bruce Norskog is to describe a (highly patterned) path through all those states _with no repetition_; without finding such a path, it's not clear at all why one should exist.  Consider five vertices connected by edges in the shape of an X -- any path connecting all the vertices has to visit the center vertex several times.  In Norskog's Hamiltonian path on the cube space, there is no redundancy, no position visited twice.

Comment: Any sequence loops after at most 1260 repetitions. (src: Wikipedia, Rubik's Cube Group) Therefore, a lower bound on the length of warspyking's sequence is 43 quintillion divided by 1260.

Comment: @Lopsy, Do you mean that for any sequence of moves $a$ in the Rubik's Cube Group, $a^{1260} = 1$?

Comment: @Joe Z.: I mean that for any sequence $a$, there exists a $k \leq 1260$ such that $a^k=1$. I have no idea whether your statement is also true. I just got this from Wikipedia.

Comment: @JoeZ. Even if you have a Hamiltonian cycle, this does not satisfy the requirements posed in the question, since you will have to stop your traversal of the cycle when the cube reaches the solved state, whereas the requirement is: "[the sequence] cannot be broken up into multiple pieces to be executed depending on Rubik's cube patterns; it must, when repeated from start to finish, end in a perfectly solved Rubik's cube"

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: This only works in a certain set of configurations, as the loop only goes through 1260 states before returning to the original position. My mistake, this is incorrect, but still useful.**

Great solution found [here](http://aperiodical.com/2014/03/how-to-solve-a-rubiks-cube-in-one-easy-step/). Basically, if you rotate the right, back, left, and front faces all clockwise and in order, then it will always solve the cube - eventually. The core part of it is in one simple explanation - doing this cannot enter an inescapable loop.

If you move the front face clockwise, then counter-clockwise, nothing happens to the cube. The faces are not moved with respect to each other, and you are in the same position. In order for a loop to happen, two different layouts **must** lead to the same configuration with the same move. But wait - if you reverse  this move, then what position does it go to? The simple answer is this will never happen. Here is a great diagram in the article itself. [image]

As you can see, reversing this loop would not work, as there are two possible options. This is a proof that loops will never happen.

Moving these four faces is the shortest possible configuration of moves that affects each and every cube, save for the center ones which are irrelevant anyway. This means it is the shortest possible solution that you could repeat to solve the Cube.

Comment: Nice! Good find!

Comment: This doesn't work for *any* configuration - only starting from a solved cube and the 1260 configurations you get while performing that sequence of moves.

Comment: @Joe Doesn't this mean it will eventually lead back to a solved cube, assuming the cube *can* be solved? You can't enter loops, so it should eventually lead back to the solved position.

Comment: No; as soon as you perform a move that's outside of the fixed sequence, performing that fixed sequence will *never* get you back to a solved cube; you'll just get another cycle of 1,260 configurations.

Comment: @Joe Ahh. I see my mistake. warspyking, this is wrong. Crap, I really thought I had it. Looks like I have to read articles more thoroughly from now on.

Comment: @mdc32 It's fine. Don't delete it though, it's great for educational purposes, just make an edit stating that it only works from the solved state returning back.

Comment: Note, in general, that any sequence of moves, if repeated enough times, will eventually get back to the original configuration. This is a property of groups.

Comment: @Joe Z: Well, it is a property of _finite_ groups.

Answer (score 3):

- Let's assume there is a sequence $A$, such that for any starting configuration $x$ there exists a number $n(x)$, such that applying $A^{n(x)}$ will solve the cube.
- It follows that given two configurations $x$ and $y$, we can move from $x$ to $y$ with $A^{n(X) - n(Y)}$. In other words, any sequence can be replaced by repeating A (or its inverse $A^{-1}$) for a specified number of times.
- From here it follows that given any two sequences: $B$ and $C$, the order of their application does not matter ($BC=CB$), since they are both composed of repeated applications of $A$ and $A^{-1}$.
- However, this is plainly wrong. It's easy to see that applying the same sequences in a different order can result in a different configuration.
- Therefore, our assumption was false, and there is no sequence such that its repeated application can solve the cube from any starting configuration.

**QED**

In mathematical language, the existence of such a sequence will make the Rubik's cube group a cyclic group (a group with 1 generator), and therefore an abelian group (a group with a commutative operation), which we know is wrong. The Rubik's cube group is normally formulated with 6 generators (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group)), and can even be formulated with 2 generators (see lemma 7.6 [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/groups.htm#conjug), h/t [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/is-it-possible-to-use-one-sequence-of-moves-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-from-any-p#comment310909_109895) by Jaap Scherphuis) , but no less.

*Why I think some of the other answers here are incorrect:*
Finding a Hamiltonian cycle does not satisfy the requirements posed in the question, since we will have to stop your traversal of the cycle when the cube reaches the solved state, whereas the requirement is: "[the sequence] cannot be broken up into multiple pieces to be executed depending on Rubik's cube patterns; it must, when repeated from start to finish, end in a perfectly solved Rubik's cube".

Comment: Interesting proof!

Comment: You mention that the Rubik's Cube group has 6 generators. While that is the obvious formulation, where each generator is a basic move, it does not mean that the group cannot be generated by fewer than 6 elements. For example, the two elements represented by the move sequences `R2FLD'R'` and `UBLUL'U'B'` generate the whole group (see lemma 7.6 [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/groups.htm#conjug) ). As you say, the group certainly cannot be generated by just one generator, but just two generators are sufficient.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - great point, thanks! I incorporated your comment in the answer.

Answer (score -3):

single move (sexy move) RUR'U' method [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBkka-fhgg4)

or 3 moves method ([Peter Renzland's method](http://dancing.org/rubik.pdf))

These all very humanly intuitive that requires minimal memorization of extra algorithms, but human reasoning.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The question was: "Is there an algorithm you can use from any scrambled configuration and position to solve the 3x3x3 Cube?" The answer is basically [Devil's Algorithm](http://anttila.ca/michael/devilsalgorithm/).