# Possible to expose each legal position of rubiks cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

Is it possible (theoretically, of course) to expose each legal rubik's cube position only once with a single sequence of quarter-turn and half-turn moves? Assume a 3x3x3 cube, and ample computing power.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use one sequence of moves to solve the Rubik's cube from any position?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/is-it-possible-to-use-one-sequence-of-moves-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-from-any-p)

Comment: @Pureferret this question has a strict requirement that *each configuration should be exposed, **only once**, in a single sequence*. It doesn't necessarily care if the end state is a solved cube, only that each legal configuration is exposed. The proposed duplicate doesn't satisfy this requirement, and as such, I'm voting to leave this open, purely for that requirement.

Comment: While the Possible Duplicate observed by @Pureferret is quite close, it answers this question indirectly; More-over, this question adds some additional requirements : Hence, I think this is not a Direct Duplicate. I think, the answers in the Possible Duplicate may be used as the Basis or Starting Point for answering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already asked:
[Is it possible to use one sequence of moves to solve the Rubik's cube from any position?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/is-it-possible-to-use-one-sequence-of-moves-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-from-any-p)
Shortcut to the answer is here: http://bruce.cubing.net/ham333/rubikhamiltonexplanation.html

Comment: Incorrect. The question states "expose each legal rubik's cube position **only once**", a completely different question. The other question asks for the shortest repeating block which can produce every position (not necessarily only once).

Comment: But the "Devil's Algorithm" as explained in that question is exactly the answer to this question, as it visits every legal position exactly once.

Comment: Yeah this answers my question. My curiosity is satiated. Thank you.

Comment: So it's possible with only quarter turns in one direction (per face) and by rotating only only five of the faces.